# What are some recommended UX Certification programs?

Tags: ux-designer, certification

I have a degree in Distance Education and E-learning. I am suddenly interested in UX/UI. I thought about getting a master's degree in UX but a certification program may be more useful.

What are some useful certification programs from reputable schools that I should consider?

Comment: Questions that are not directly related to actual UX problems and to do with training and education are best discussed in chatrooms or in other forums such as Quora, where there are already plenty of topics and answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at Nielsen Norman Group certification  : https://www.nngroup.com/ux-certification/

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on this decision!

**There are SO many of this type of program, and with such different foci and scope that you want to have some idea of what you want to get out of it**, and do good research into the programs that will meet those goals.

My personal "gold standard" is the [bootcamps offered by Bentley University](https://www.bentley.edu/centers/ux-education) (where I did my [grad program](https://www.bentley.edu/academics/graduate-programs/masters-human-factors)). It looks like they've changed their format for non-degree classes somewhat, but they have several offerings from a couple of days to a week that offer broad skills and certification.

Another good option to look at, at least as a first pass, is the [Google UX Design certificate](https://grow.google/certificates/ux-design/#?modal_active=none), which you can still do largely for free on Coursera, I believe. If you have LinkedIn premier you have access to LinkedIn Learning which has a number of excellent UX courses that can give you some digital credential upon completion. There are MANY others, from free online-only courses to fully immersive programs from prestigious academic institutions.

**Definitely have some idea what your goals are!** Career pivot, larger paycheck, certain types of work, new industry, specific skills... there are a lot of reasons to look into educating yourself, and knowing what those are will help you weed through the options to find what is right for you.

**Also try to understand what each program will give you.** Some of these courses will focus on "full stack" UX, giving broad overviews of everything from requirements gathering, generative research, and information architecture through workflows and wireframes, prototyping, visual design, usability testing, front end development; others will focus more squarely on one or another part of the UX spectrum. Some may include aspects of human physiology and psychology that can be very valuable to know as underpinnings of things like gestalt design principles and color choices; others may include actual coding and programming essentials to make you a better collaborator with your development partners, or content development and management.

**A possibly fruitful path:** Take one or two free, "broad-spectrum" online overview programs to get a sense of all the different aspects of UX that a well-rounded UX professional should be at least FAMILIAR with, and then determine which of those really spark your curiosity and find a more in-depth program for that.

In fact, if you want **a pretty solid, quick overview to the UX field and ideas for how to break into it**, I led a presentation on this very thing at my last company - it was aimed at young folks trying to break in to the field; the concepts in this recording still hold for anyone new to the field, and the resources links at the end could be very useful.
https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/564775896

Also note that if you want credentials to prove you've got some skills you'll need to generally pay more for the certificate or degree; free programs that provide badges and completions are good and the curricula can be very valid and useful, but they might not carry the same cred with employers unless paired with experience and/or portfolio material.

Good luck! It is an exciting and still very badly needed (if still misunderstood) field - let me know if I can help any further.